# Intermediate value of the derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

[image]

Hi all what would the best way be to approach this question?
I tried using the hint but I can't seem to formulate an answer for the fist part.
Any help for the first and second parts of the question will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as for i), note that the continuous function $g$ attains a maximum and a minumum on $[a,b]$, and the hint tells you it is not a boundary point. So it is somewhere in $(a,b)$... What do you know about the derivative of a function in a maximum/minimum?

Comment: As for (ii), see Boas _A Pimer of Real Functions_ (1981) p. 144.